# Why would the statement not work

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++ programming and I am supposed to create a program in which answers that does not meet certain conditions would produce certain statements.
I also added

```
 cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

in order to use

```
getline
```

and 
    cin

together. However, I think I may have misunderstood the nature of how they work and I used

```
 cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')
```

before using the first getline function, and it was causing my program to pause. I think that I am supposed to use this only if i use cin before, and when I want to use a getline function in order to prevent the getline function from taking in the empty space?

at the start, and it is causing me errors, I'm not sure when I use this. 
I think this part might be the error... but I'm not quite for how the || and the && operators work

```
else if (donorGender != "Male" || "Female" || "Trans Male" || "Trans Female" || "Queer" || "Different")
```

is this it the way I do it?

```
else if (donorGender != "Male" && donorGender != "Female" && donorGender != "Trans Male" && donorGender != "Trans Female" && donorGender != "Queer" && donorGender != "Different")
```

or is this the way I do it

Please help...

Comment: `else if (donorGender != "Male" || "Female" || "Trans Male" || "Trans Female" || "Queer" || "Different")` is not right. That needs to be `else if ( donorGender != "Male" && donerGener != "Female" .&& .. )`.

Comment: If you are looking for a code review, you want to post this question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Daniel Code Review is for working code. This question would be closed there.

Comment: you just removed the code from your question.

Comment: Mistake, readding it

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I edited it to make my question more comprehensive for readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

is pausing your program at the start until you press `Enter` key.

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/):

> std::istream::ignore
>
> istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);
>
> Extract and discard characters
>
> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim.

Generally, `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')` used with `getline` if you have some other input statements using `cin` before calling `getline` because when a user inputs something with `cin`, they hit `Enter` key and a `\n` (newline) character gets into the input buffer. Then if your program calling `getline`, it gets the newline character instead of the string you want. In your program you are is using `getline` for the first input from the user, so you don't need it. You can safely remove `cin.ignore` statement from your program.

This statement is wrong:

```
else if (donorGender != "Male" || "Female" || "Trans Male" || "Trans Female" || "Queer" || "Different")
```

You need to compare `donorGender` with all the possible valid values and not only with just one valid value. Even if you compare `donorGender !=` with all valid values this will not work because `||` operator in the condition will always evaluate to `true` as a valid value of `donorGender` will be `!=` rest of all valid values. Change it to:

```
else if (donorGender != "Male" && donorGender != "Female" && donorGender != "Trans Male" && donorGender != "Trans Female" && donorGender != "Queer" && donorGender != "Different")
```

With these changes, your program should work as expected.
Also, I would suggest you to add some input validation for all the inputs you are taking from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says that it will test `donorName` else `donorGender` and so on. You need to check all the conditions. and your `donorGender` checking if statement is not correctly formatted. **What if user enters both name and gender invalid!**

I think you should not check other conditions if one if false. if you want to tell all the wrong things then approach is different. but in your case below code can help. try it out!

**Nested Conditional Statements**

```
if(donorName != "") 
{
    if(donorGender == "Male" 
        or donorGender == "Female" 
        or donorGender == "Trans Male" 
        or donorGender == "Trans Female" 
        or donorGender == "Queer"
        or donorGender =="Different") 
    {
        if(donorAge >= 0) {
            if(donorWeight >= 0) {
                if (donorHeight >= 0)
                {
                    cout << "--- You must enter a valid height." << endl;
                    return (-1);
                }
                else {

                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "--- You must enter a valid weight." << endl;
                return (-1);    
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "--- You must enter a valid age." << endl;
            return (-1);
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "--- You must enter a valid gender." << endl;
        return(-1);
    }
} 
else {
    cout << " --- You must enter a valid name." << endl;
    return (-1);
}
```